# Homotopy pullback square implies weak equivalence of homotopy fibres

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I am quite confused about the following situation: suppose that we have a map $f \colon X \to Y$. Its homotopy fibre is defined as the pullback of the following of diagram:

\begin{matrix}
Ff & {\rightarrow} & * \\
\downarrow{} && \downarrow{} \\
X & \rightarrow{} & Y
\end{matrix}

Now if $g \colon W \to Z$ is another map and the diagram
\begin{matrix}
W & {\rightarrow} & X \\
\downarrow{} && \downarrow{} \\
Z & {\rightarrow} & Y
\end{matrix}

is homotopy cartesian, why does it follow that the homotopy fibres of $f$ and $g$ are weakly equivalent?

Comment: In ordinary category theory, if I delete the word "homotopy" and replace "weakly equivalent" by "isomorphic", this follows from the pullback pasting lemma. I imagine something similar is true in the homotopy world.